# Travel by car in Argentina, L/100 km or km/L is used for car fuel economy?

Tags: budget

I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km (liter per 100 km). Some countries use km/Liter (km per liter).

My question is: which format Argentina people use?

L/100 km or km/L?

Comment: How does this affect travellers?

Comment: UK and USA use miles per gallon (and annoyingly use different gallons, so the numbers are different). Never heard of any place that does km / Liter. Apart from that, I recommend using a pocket calculator.

Comment: In the Netherlands, and likely more European countries, km/l is what used to be used, now the standard is supposed to be L/100km (with the useless change of l into L on top of the different order) and nobody much uses it in daily life.

Answer (score 2):

According to [auto magazines](http://www.mundoautomotor.com.ar/web/2013/11/14/volkswagen-golf-tdi-bluemotion-29-l-100-km-de-consumo/), **L / 100 km** seems to be the accepted standard. However **km / L** is sometimes used unofficially on [forums and blogs](http://www.clubranger4x4.com.ar/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=36758). Either way converting from one to the other is simple.